# Draw curve arrow , place arrow head in right location

Tags: java, graphics, paint

I am painting a curve arrow using java,

but I can't place to arrow head in the right location .

can you help me please

This is what I done so far,
icon should be dynamic size, so all should be painted according to the
`m_size` variable

Thank you.

```java
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Object hintOriginal = g2.getRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); 
    
    int strokeSize = m_size / 6;
    
    Stroke strokeOriginal = g2.getStroke();
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
    
    g2.drawArc(x + (strokeSize / 2), y + (strokeSize / 2), m_size - (strokeSize * 2), m_size - (strokeSize * 2), 45, 180);

    g2.setStroke(strokeOriginal);

    int arrSize = (m_size / 4) + strokeSize;
    int[] xArr = new int[3];
    int[] yArr = new int[3];
    
    xArr[0] = x;
    xArr[1] = x + arrSize;
    xArr[2] = x + (arrSize / 2);

    yArr[0] = y;
    yArr[1] = y;
    yArr[2] = y - (arrSize / 2);

    AffineTransform  origXform = g2.getTransform();
    AffineTransform newXform  = (AffineTransform) (origXform.clone());
    
    newXform.rotate(Math.toRadians(135), x + m_size / 2, y + m_size / 2);
    g2.setTransform(newXform);

    g2.fillPolygon(xArr, yArr, 3);
    
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, hintOriginal);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us where you wanted the arrowhead to be, and where it is actually being drawn.